# Get the original image from Imgur URLs with "maxwidth", "shape", and "fidelity"

Tags: image, imgur

Imgur doesn't seem to give out the original image for some images, for example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4cLI.jpg?maxwidth=123456789&shape=thumb&fidelity=high

The problem is that I bet "shape=thumb" and "fidelity=high" are downgrading the original image.

Does not give me the original:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4cLI.jpg

Does not exist:

https://imgur.com/hJCEq8P_d

https://imgur.com/a/hJCEq8P_d

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4cLI.jpg` would be it in an ideal world, but it is not.

Is there a fidelity higher than "high"? Is there a shape better than "thumb"? I just want the original image or the best possible version of it, and Imgur is jerking me around and stupidly wasting my time by not giving me that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the "_d":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmSWP.jpg

has a better quality than

https://i.imgur.com/hJCEq8P_d.jpg?maxwidth=123456789&shape=thumb&fidelity=high

I think that Imgur idioticly compresses all JPEGs uploaded there, so the JPEG file on a user's hard drive and the Imgur-uploaded version of that file are not bit-identical and the online version is lower quality. My point is that I guess the actual original image is unreachable unless it is linked in the image's description on the Imgur page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (at least not on mobile). The link without "_d" just redirects to the image's imgur page.

Comment: This still works on mobile. Just request a desktop site to view the image instead of the imgur page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after further testing, and just for the sanity of anyone else looking into this just like I was: the best quality image you can save off Imgur seems to be a PNG with "_d" after the imgcode filename (i.e. "01234_d.png"), maxwidth set to something high like 10000, and fidelity set to "high". So for example: https://i.imgur.com/F973T_d.png?maxwidth=10000&fidelity=high

More info and testing notes can be found here: https://github.com/ImguRandom/ImguRandom.com/wiki/Imgur-API-Shit